# Adding column to temporary table with select statments

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure I'm trying to create to fill a temporary table.  But I need to make several passes at adding data based upon some conditions and capture those conditions with an additional field added to the temp table.

I start out like this:

```
 select top 0 
 into #mytable
 from UserTable
```

This I have found simply copies the basic structure with the same columns and types.  Then I need to add a field:

```
 alter table #mytable ADD reasontype varchar
```

The I make several passes at examining the table, here is one of them:

```
 insert into #mytable
 select distinct a.*, 'Annual'
 from UserTable a
 where (a.EnrollmentDate < DATEADD(year, -1, getdate())
```

This is to select those that require an annual review.  The procedure compiles without an error but when I try to fill a datatable I get the error that string or binary data would be truncated.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a length on your varchar.  ('Annual' is being truncated to 'A')

Comment: @Tibrogargan that's the answer; you should submit it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    alter table #mytable ADD reasontype varchar(max)
```

If that works, either use "max" or a value that won't truncate your values...or use a LEFT statement where the length matches the longest value of reasontype

example for left:

```
alter table #mytable ADD reasontype varchar(3)


 insert into #mytable
 select distinct a.*, LEFT('Annual',3)
 from UserTable a
 where (a.EnrollmentDate < DATEADD(year, -1, getdate())
```

but you probably just want this:

```
alter table #mytable ADD reasontype varchar(6) /* where 6 is the length of the string "Annual" */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a length on your varchar, 'Annual' is being truncated to 'A'.  If you're planning on indexing the reasontype field, don't use varchar(max), it exceeds the maximum width of an indexable field